# How can edit the SMS_RECEIVED settings?

Tags: android, sms, android-vibration

Is there a way to override the settings so that if I receive a sms nothing happens, or at least there is no vibration and no sound?

Answer (score 1):

You can write a broadcastReceiver class for receiving the SMS,and call the

```
abortbroadcast();
```

for aborting the broadcast of the SMS came,and can prevent it from being into the notification and to the Inbox;rather you can save the SMS to a string easily....Try it...

Comment: if I do that, everything that happens normally if i receive a sms doesn't work? How can I exactly store the message how it is usually done?

Comment: when the method abortbroadcast() is called,actually the sms broadcast is aborted...after this,you can write the code to retreive the sms...